# What does this error means "Exception Value: `update()` must be implemented." in django restframework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-3.0

I am trying to make a web service of choice field using Django rest framework. My data base connectivity is working but when I post my web service it gives me the error:- : **`update()` must be implemented."**

I am attaching my code below

My dashboard/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class Campus(models.Model):
    campus_choices = (('Campus_1','Campus_1'),('Campus_2','Campus_2'),('Campus_3','Campus_3'))
    select_campus = models.CharField(max_length = 100,choices = campus_choices)


class Building(models.Model):
    building_choices = (('Building_1','Building_1'),('Building_2','Building_2'),('Building_3','Building_3'))
    select_building = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = building_choices)

class Floor(models.Model):
    floor_choices = (('Floor_1','Floor_1'),('Floor_2','Floor_2'),('Floor_3','Floor_3'))
    select_floor = models.CharField(max_length = 100,choices = floor_choices)

class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_choices = (('Room_1','Room_1'),('Room_2','Room_2'),('Room_3','Room_3'))
    select_rooms = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = room_choices)
```

serializers.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from dashboard.models import Campus

class CampusSerializers(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        campus_choices = [('Campus_1','Campus_1'),('Campus_2','Campus_2'),('Campus_3','Campus_3')]

        model = Campus

        select_campus = serializers.ChoiceField(choices = campus_choices)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            campus_obj = Campus(**validated_data)
            campus_obj.save()
            return campus_obj

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.select_campus = validated_data["select_campus"]
            instance.save()
            return instance


class BuildingSerializers(models.Model):
    select_building = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        building_obj = Building(**validated_data)
        building_obj.save()
        return building_obj

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.select_building = validated_data["select_building"]
        instance.save()
        return instance

class FloorSerializers(models.Model):
    select_floor = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        floor_obj = Floor(**validated_data)
        floor_obj.save()
        return floor_obj

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.select_floor = validated_data["select_floor"]
        instance.save()
        return instance

class RoomsSerializers(models.Model):
    select_rooms = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        room_obj = Floor(**validated_data)
        room_obj.save()
        return room_obj

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.select_room = validated_data["select_room"]
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from dashboard.serializers import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import *
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['POST'])
def add_campus(request):
    campus_serializer = CampusSerializer(data=request.data)
    if campus_serializer.is_valid():
        campus_serializer.save()
        return Response({"data": "Campus added successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error_details = []
        for key in campus_serializer.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": campus_serializer.errors[key][0]})

        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_building(request):
    building_serializer = BuildingSerializers(data=request.data)
    if building_serializer.is_valid():
        building_serializer.save()
        return Response({"data": "Campus added successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error_details = []
        for key in building_serializer.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": building_serializer.errors[key][0]})

        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['POST'])
def add_floor(request):
    floor_serializer = FloorSerializers(data=request.data)
    if floor_serializer.is_valid():
        floor_serializer.save()
        return Response({"data": "Campus added successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error_details = []
        for key in floor_serializer.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": floor_serializer.errors[key][0]})

        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['POST'])
def add_rooms(request):
    rooms_serializer = RoomsSerializers(data=request.data)
    if rooms_serializer.is_valid():
        rooms_serializer.save()
        return Response({"data": "Campus added successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        error_details = []
        for key in rooms_serializer.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": rooms_serializer.errors[key][0]})

        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['POST'])
def campus_details(request):
    try:
        dashboard = Campus.objects.all()
    except Campus.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CampusSerializers(dashboard, data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else: 
            error_details = []
        for key in serializer.errors.keys():
            error_details.append({"field": key, "message": serializer.errors[key][0]})

        data = {
                "Error": {
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "error_details": error_details
                    }
                }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


        update= get_object_or_404(Campus)
        form = CampusSerializers(request.POST or None, instance=update)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('campus_details')
    elif request.method != 'POST':
        return False
```

It is showing me NotImplimented error like this

[This is the exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdG7f.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should user a `ModelSerializer` here instead of simple `Serializer`. So, instead of this:

```
class CampusSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
```

use this:

```
class CampusSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

Check the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Also, if you still want to user simple serializer, your formatting is incorrect, then you just put create/update method inside `Meta` class. They should be inside serializer class.

Comment: You forgot to update your answer to use ModelSerializer

Comment: I just realized that perhaps the problem is in indent - create and update methods are inside meta class, not inside serializer.